# Python: convert string to datetime object failed if the format is with comma

Tags: python, datetime

So i try to convert my string to `date time` object without knowing the `format` this way:

```
date = '019-03-13 17:35:35.855'
date_object = datetime.fromisoformat(date)
```

So this works fine but in case the `datetime` object failed if the format is with `comma` this fail:

```
date = '019-03-13 17:35:35,855'
date_object = datetime.fromisoformat(date)
```

> ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2019-03-13 17:35:35,855'

And most of my `files` written with this `comma` format.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Preprocessing or use strftime.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.fromisoformat` expects you to send a string in a [particular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) format:

> Specifically, this function supports strings in the format(s) `YYYY-MM-DD[*HH[:MM[:SS[.fff[fff]]]][+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]]]`, where * can match any single character.

If your format differs, you should use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?#datetime.datetime.strptime) and set [your format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) in it. If you have no single format or you have dirty data, the only way you can to process it is to clean it first with some kind of data refining function.